# Xcode 5: Counterparts per default in Assistant Editor

Tags: editor, xcode5

I started developing apps with Xcode 5 and I wonder about the behavior of the Assistant Editor. A few weeks ago it always opened the counterpart of a file (opening a .h file it opened the corresponding .m file and so on).

Since a few weeks it always opens a "random" file in "Manual" mode so I always have to switch back to "Counterparts" manually.

Does anyone know if there is an option (anywhere deep within Xcode configuration) to get the old behavior back? It's pretty annoying to start typing and then realize that I've changed a file I didn't want to change.

Searching this forum led me to a thread which suggested to delete the "derived files". I did so (restarted Xcode and re-built the project) but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Alex